# How to update data and legend in Forio Contour

Tags: forio-contour

I would like to have a dynamic chart. I would like to add new series and even change values of an old series that appear on Forio Contour. I took one of Forio's examples and changed it:

```js
$(function () {
    var myContour = new Contour({
            el: '.line-multi-basic',
            xAxis: {
                title: 'Group Size',
                type: 'linear'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: 'Test Score'
            },
            legend: {
                vAlign: 'top',
                hAlign: 'left'
            }
        }).cartesian();

    var redLine = [{x: 0, y: 170},{x: 88, y: 170},{x: 178, y: 149},{x: 201, y: 106},{x: 287, y: 83},{x: 331, y: 105},{x: 353, y: 172},{x: 400, y: 219}];
    var greenLine = [{x: 0, y: 220},{x: 87, y: 130},{x: 154, y: 197},{x: 197, y: 195},{x: 220, y: 214},{x: 286, y: 215},{x: 332, y: 263},{x: 378, y: 241}, {x: 400, y: 242}];
    var blueLine = [{x: 0, y: 103},{x: 44, y: 103},{x: 154, y: 36},{x: 309, y: 150},{x: 376, y: 150},{x: 400, y: 171}];

    var data = [{name: 'Math', data: redLine}];
    myContour.line(data).tooltip().legend(data).render();

    data = [{name: 'Math', data: redLine},
            {name: 'Economics', data: greenLine}];
    myContour.line(data).tooltip().legend(data).render();
    
    data = [{name: 'Math', data: redLine},
            {name: 'Economics', data: greenLine},
            {name: 'History', data: blueLine}];
    myContour.line(data).tooltip().legend(data).render();
    
    //update redLine and reconstruct data
    var redLine = [{x: 0, y: 70},{x: 88, y: 70},{x: 178, y: 49},{x: 201, y: 6},{x: 287, y: 3},{x: 331, y: 5},{x: 353, y: 72},{x: 400, y: 19}];
    data = [{name: 'Math', data: redLine},
            {name: 'Economics', data: greenLine},
            {name: 'History', data: blueLine}];
    myContour.line(data).tooltip().legend(data).render();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://forio.com/tools/contour/contour.min.css">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="http://forio.com/tools/contour/contour.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart line-multi-basic"></div>
```

The legend does not change with data updates!
Also, when I update one of the series, it just draws a new one!

Comment: I was able to update the data using `myContour.setData(data)` instead of `myContour.line(data)`. However, this is not helping with the legend!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the version of contour that you are using and that was subsequently fixed, if you change the script (and css) include lines to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://forio.com/tools/contour/0.9.114/contour.min.css">
<script src="https://forio.com/tools/contour/0.9.114/contour.min.js"></script>
```

you should be able to call `chart.setData(...).render()` and the legend should update correctly.